# CakePHP: grouping by children table column

Tags: cakephp, orm

I am not sure about the right way how to apply group by on child table.

Users have many Articles.

Below will results in error:

```
$UsersTable= $this->getTableLocator()->get('Users');

$query = $UsersTable->find();

$query->contain(["Articles"]);

$query->group(["Articles.type"]); // ERROR
```

Adding matching resolves the issue, but is it how it suppose to work?

```
$UsersTable= $this->getTableLocator()->get('Users');
$query = $UsersTable->find();
$query->contain(["Articles"]);
// just calling matching without any condition
$query->matching(
  "Articles", function($q) {
    return $q;
  }
);
$query->group(["Articles.type"]); // WORKS!
```

Isn't there another proper way to get this working, without relying on matching?

Comment: The reason the latter works is that matching causes a join, whereas simple containment runs as a second query. But what does it even mean to get users grouped by article type? You haven't used any aggregate function (count, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

first you have to join between `Users` and `Articles` by one of join methods like `matching` ,... then you can use `group()` method

`contain()` does not use join for all cases especially for your relation: `hasMany`

mysql's `group by` needs a join between these tables to work

Comment: Thank you very much, your reply makes perfect sense. So there no way to somehow group by contained table(hasMany)? The queries I work with are much more complicated than that and it seems wrong to rely on empty matching, just to be able to group by it.